# What arguments for self-defined functions for use on list of data frames in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments

So I have been working on a script that does some data analysis automaticallly instead of having  the user do everything by hand in excel. I want R to put all sheets of a given Excel file as data frames in a list and do something to every one of those data frames using self defined functions.
Here is my code so far:

```
###Install required packages if necessary

if(!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse")
if(!require("fs")) install.packages("fs")
if(!require("readxl")) install.packages("readxl")
if(!require("matrixStats")) iinstall.packages("matrixStats")

###Load required packages

library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(readxl)
library(matrixStats)

###Define functions

#Import all sheets into a list from an Excel file

read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
}

#Subtract "Background" column from corresponding measurement column 

correct_background <- function(df) {
  cols <- grep('^\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)
  new_cols <- paste0(cols, '_corrected')
  df[new_cols] <- df[cols] - df[paste0('Background ', cols)]
  }

#Calculate means and standard deviations and drop "_corrected" columns

mean_SD <- function(df) {
  df$mean <- rowMeans(select(df, contains("_corrected")))
  df$SD <- rowSds(as.matrix(select(df, contains("_corrected"))))
  df <- subset(df, select = c("Wavelength", "mean", "SD"))
}

###Apply functions

#Load all Excel sheets of chosen file into a list of data frames

mysheets <- read_excel_allsheets(file.choose())

#Apply background correction on every data frame in the list

lapply(mysheets, correct_background)

#Apply function to calculate mean and SD

lapply(mysheets, mean_SD)
```

Now where it flops is in the `###Apply functions` part. The first function, the one to load the Excel sheets works fine, but I think I need to define an argument for the second and third function that tells them they should work over any data frame in the list regardless of its name. Is there a default way to refer to every data frame within a list in R? Or do I need to define that by hand?
Help much appreciated!

Comment: `lapply` will your `correct_background` and `mean_SD` functions to every element in the `myheets` list, but you need to save its return value to observe results. You need to use the output from `correct_background` as the input to `mean_SD` as well, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the results of the `lapply` operations. Change your `lapply` statements to the following.

```r
#Apply background correction on every data frame in the list

mysheets <- lapply(mysheets, correct_background)

#Apply function to calculate mean and SD

mysheets <- lapply(mysheets, mean_SD)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I keep running into the same problem however, where if I `lapply` the `correct_background` function on the list, R returns the "undefined columns selected" error. If I isolate one data frame and use the functions lines individually on that data frame, it works just fine.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share some examples of the original column names in your excel file?

Comment: Have been able to figure a way around it, thanks again though for the help!

Comment: "undefined columns selected" would occur when there is column in your original df that doesn't fit into the neat design of `paste0('Background ', cols)`. Maybe, just maybe, there is one column that has an extra space or some other character. Again, I would like to know the original column names to be accurate.